# PCL MLS-Processing: No output point cloud

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, surface, normals

I'm quite new to PCL and so I don't know how I can debug this. In a tutorial I found code for surface smoothing and normal calculation based on MLS. Everytime, I want to execute this code snippet I get an empty point cloud. I tested it on the file commited in the tutorial where it functioned and on a other point cloud commited in an other tutorial. Here, the MLS-algorithm returned a point cloud, but every normal was 0. I would be glad, if someone could help me. Is there maybe a processing limits of points? My point cloud has 4.5 million points and is a scan of a UAV.

```
// Load input file into a PointCloud<T> with an appropriate type
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> ());

  // Create a KD-Tree
  pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>);

  // Output has the PointNormal type in order to store the normals calculated by MLS
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointNormal> mls_points;

  // Init object (second point type is for the normals, even if unused)
  pcl::MovingLeastSquares<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointNormal> mls;

  mls.setComputeNormals (true);

  // Set parameters
  mls.setInputCloud (cloud);
  mls.setPolynomialOrder (2);
  mls.setSearchMethod (tree);
  mls.setSearchRadius (0.03);

  // Reconstruct
  mls.process (mls_points);
```

Comment: You might want to upload the point cloud file(.pcd) too. Also need to make sure that the unit is in meter, not millimeter, based on your setSearchRadius

Comment: I found the problem, thanks!